# Open a Bootstrap Modal automatically from an external link

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a page with 4-5 different modals attached to it. Each with a unique #value (obv). 
I am trying to find a way to link to these individual modals' from an external source (in this case an HTML email).

For example:

"Click here to view directions" in the email needs to link to -->> www.myurl.com/#directions

the #directions piece should trigger the :   function on page load and have the modal automatically open.

Is this possible or am i only dreaming?

Comment: It may be possible, but much easier to do it via get parameter: `http://www.myurl.com/index.php?direction=thisway`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the hastag to decide the content to show. For example,

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var target = document.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    if (target.length) {
        if(target=="option1"){
          showModal("title1","content1");
        }
        else if(target=="option2"){
            showModal("title2","content2");
        }
    }else{
        showModal("no title","no content");
    }

    function showModal(title,content){
        $('#myModal .modal-title').html(title);
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html(content);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

});
```

**HTML - Bootstrap modal code**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">...</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

*this will show content for option1*

http://jsfiddle.net/fFcS2/show/#option1

*this will show content for option2*

http://jsfiddle.net/fFcS2/show/#option2

*the code*

http://jsfiddle.net/fFcS2

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the delay in coming back... your solution worked 100%.
Just as I already had multiple modals, i modified the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var target = document.location.hash.replace("#", "");
if (target.length) {
    if(target=="modal1link"){
      $('#modal1').modal('show');
    }
    else if(target=="modal2link"){
      $('#modal2').modal('show');
    }
else if(target=="modal3link"){
      $('#modal3').modal('show');
    }
}else{    
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone comes here looking for a dynamic solution (where you don't have to pre-define modal ids), here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url = window.location.href;
    var modalToOpen = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));

    if(window.location.href.indexOf(modalToOpen) != -1) {
        $(modalToOpen).modal("show");
    }
});
```

This script grabs the current URL, finds the id after the hash in the URL, and then shows the modal with corresponding id.

Comment: This works great except if you also need to jump within same page, does not work for external links only. If any internal hrefs breaks other jquery plugins like easing/smooth scroll, wow, etc.